Call on Sim2 is not picked
I have 2 sims in my Samsung A04s phone. The issue is, on Sim2 if someone calls me, it rings, I can slide up the phone icon to receive call but afterwards on the top it still shows "Incoming Call" and never show the timer. Although phone stops ringing but it never go though call...
I can receive msgs, and can also call from my Sim2... but receiving is a problem.

A04s is an LTE phone. From carrier is the SIM card in your Sim2 slot and in which country are you in? Have you enabled VoLTE in your phone (on one or both of the sim cards)? Does the SIM card in Sim2 slot have a data plan active?
